# AngularJS directive: $timeout alternative

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using angularJS 1.6 directive to add some jQuery libs. Now i'm using it so:

```
let SomeDirective = function ($timeout) {
  'ngInject';

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

      $timeout(function () {
        element.somePlugin(JSON.parse(attrs.params));
      });

    }
  };
};

export default SomeDirective;
```

due to that fact, that I set some-directive on html object, which is loaded from the server, i think angular didn't understand, when apply this directive...

But i think this approach is strange and ugly... How can i fix this directive?

By the way, adding in scope `isLoaded` variable (and watch it in directive) didn't resolve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $scope.$evalAsync(). Refer https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope.

Comment: can you provide additional data? in my case it's not working in every case

Comment: can you explain what you exactly want??

Comment: plugin isn't executed...

if i change `timeout(function () {` to `scope.$evalAsync(function () {`

Comment: What's the problem with $timeout??

Comment: yes, it is that's why it is there. It is suitable for your situation because you need to wait for some time so that plugin gets initialized.